# New user created as Participant rather than Contributor

Tags: user-roles, buddypress, user-registration

On Wordpress settings we have it set such that a new user should be created as a Contributor:

[image: User Settings]

However, any users that are created are given a role of Participant:

[image: New User as Participant]

This means that they cannot create their own blog. I am pretty certain that this hasn't always been the case.

For further information we are running:

- Wordpress 3.9
- BuddyPress
- WangGuard

I cannot see any setting in these that might affect the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: "Participant" role isn't present in WP core. Do you have an idea where it's coming from in general?

Comment: I suspect Buddypress but I can find no way of changing it.

Comment: Somewhat late to the party I see that this has been closed as off-topic. Can't for the life of me understand why as there is no coding discussed at all only Wordpress functionality. @kaiser care to explain?

Comment: Please take this question to [meta] if you want to discuss what is on-topic (details in the [help/on-topic]) and what is not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer it seems is a bug in the plugin BP Disable Activation Reloaded:

```
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/user-role-bp-20-21
```